# WPF Combo Box Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, combobox

I am trying to bind a combo box with some data.
The problem is that I have the data in the combo box like this:

```
                            <ComboBox>
                                <ComboBoxItem>Item 1</ComboBoxItem>
                                <ComboBoxItem>Item 2</ComboBoxItem>
                                <ComboBoxItem>Item 3</ComboBoxItem>
                                <ComboBoxItem>Item 4</ComboBoxItem>
                                <ComboBoxItem>Item 5</ComboBoxItem>
                            </ComboBox>
```

when the form with the combo box is loaded I have a Resource loaded that has an int that I want to bind it to this combo box.
So if that int is 1 i want the combo box to show Item 1 etc. and when I change the item of the combo box I want to update that int accordingly.

Is there a way to bind this resource to the combo box to achive that?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 6):

Here is a complete XAML sample on how to do this:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
    Title="Window1">
    <Window.Resources>
        <sys:Int32 x:Key="TheIndex">2</sys:Int32>
    </Window.Resources>
    <ComboBox SelectedIndex="{Binding Source={StaticResource TheIndex}, Mode=OneWay}">
        <ComboBoxItem>One</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem>Two</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem>Three</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem>Four</ComboBoxItem>
    </ComboBox>
</Window>
```

Note the following:

- the `sys` XML namespace is declared as a mapping to the `System` CLR namespace in the *mscorlib* assembly
- the `Binding` on `SelectedIndex` is set to `OneWay` because it defaults to `TwoWay`, which makes no sense when binding directly to a resource

Comment: Hello Kent
Thanks for your reply
I am fearly new to wpf programming and I need some more explenation to the snipset you posted.
How do I declare the 
<sys:Int32 x:Key="TheIndex">2</sys:Int32>
and how is that bound to my resource?

Thank you again

Comment: @Taonias: no problem. I've updated my post with a complete, working example.